# Listen to key press Enter in Quill

Tags: javascript, quill

```
const editor = new Quill(selector, {

theme: 'snow',
modules: {
    keyboard: {
        bindings,
    }
```

IM use quilljs js keyboard module https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/
tried two variants

```
bindings.handleEnter = {
        key: 13,
        handler: () => { console.log(45656); },

};
bindings['enter'] = {
        key: 13,
        handler: () => { console.log(45656); },

};
```

But not work enter code. Other key code works

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `addBinding()` method to add a new key binding for the enter key?

Comment: Im use https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/#configuration other key code workd, but enter not work

Comment: You cannot modify bindings after QuillJS has been initialized. I.e. if you're adding new properties to `bindings` after invoking `new Quill()`, this will not work. Can you show us a [mcve]?

Comment: It turned out that he does not see the code, but he sees the name of the button with a capital letter    // bindings['enter'] = {
    //     key: 'Enter',
    //     handler: () => { console.log(45656); },
    //
    // };

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that he does not see the code, but he sees the name of the button with a capital letter. It works

```
bindings['enter'] = {
    key: 'Enter',
    handler: () => { console.log(45656); },

};
```